# Unexpected output Signed and Unsigned comparison in for loop

Tags: c

```
unsigned int array[5],length = 5;

for(int i = -1; i < length; ++i)
{
    array[i] = i;
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Output: No Output // nothing is printing

I am expecting It should print the array.

Why no output of this c code ? What is the reason ?

Comment: What do you think `array[-1] = i;` does?

Comment: Undefined behavior ?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: but after incrementing it should print 0 ?

Comment: @hetepeperfan not exactly, since the loop body is never entered due to the problem in the loop condition

Comment: @M.M Please tell me the exact problem  as a answer of question?

Comment: @PankajSuryawanshi it should be marked as duplicate, this is a common question

Comment: I dont think it is duplicate ? share me link of answer if its duplicate

Comment: Habe you seen any "signed vs unsigned mismatch" warnins from your compiler lately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of `i` and `length` are different (int and unsigned int respectively). So in the comparison `i < length`, `i` gets converted to an `unsigned int` because `unsigned int` has higher rank as per [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

The value of `-1` converted to `unsigned int` is `UINT_MAX`. Thus the comparison is equivalent to `UINT_MAX < 5` in the first iteration. Which is false and the loop is never entered.

Comment: Also note that, even if `length` was signed, an optimizing compiler could still decide to remove the entire loop, because it would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant. As it is, the body isn't executed because of the loop condition. However, if `length` was declared as signed, then all possible code paths contain undefined behavior. A fact which many optimizing compilers will happily use to optimize away the entire loop. Usually when talking about UB, people say "literally anything can happen", and while that is indeed what the standard implies, in practice one of the most common side-effects of UB (if not the most common) are unexpected optimizations.